# Can't I ask about other (Debian based) distros as well as Ubuntu?

Tags: support

As Ubuntu is based on Debian and there are other flavors of it like Kubuntu, Xubuntu, MATE, EdUbuntu, Lubuntu and so on, is asking about Mint or Debian or other Debian-based distros on topic here? Or should I ask about it on Unix and Linux stack exchange ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We support any offical distributions, currenty, these are

- Edubuntu (14.04)
- Ubuntu GNOME
- Kubuntu
- Ubuntu Kylin
- Lubuntu
- Mythbuntu (16.04)
- Ubuntu Studio
- Xubuntu
- Ubuntu MATE
- Ubuntu Touch
- Ubuntu Budgie (17.04+)
- Ubuntu "Snappy" Core.

See the [help center](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) for more detail, we do not support Mint or Debian or anything else not on this list.

Comment: I mean debian based distro not ubuntu. Just like mint, debian, kdeneon and all those based on debian.

Comment: No you can't, this is all of the ones we support, as you said http://unix.stackexchange.com or they are welcome on http://superuser.com Specifically Elementary OS has its own site like this one http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It'd be more helpful on superuser or unixlinux than being questions off topic.